# Cannot make user directory on a new CDH5 installation (Hadoop)

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

I download and installed CDH 5 package succesfully on a single linux node in pseudo-distributed Mode on my CentOS 6.5

Starting Hadoop and verifying it is Working Properly as in [this link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Quick-Start/cdh5qs_mrv1_pseudo.html)

I succesfully finished the following steps

Step 1: Format the NameNode.

Step 2: Start HDFS

Step 3: Create the /tmp Directory

Step 4: Create the MapReduce system directories:

Step 5: Verify the HDFS File Structure

Step 6: Start MapReduce

while following command in step 7 I get the following error.

Step 7: Create User Directories

***$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoopuser***

***mkdir: '/user/hadoopuser': No such file or directory***

(where hadoopuser is my linux login username)

If I create the directory manually as /user/hadoopuser in the filesystem, it is not accepting.

How to success the step 7:?

Please provide the sloution to procced the remaining installation.

Comment: try `sudo hadoop fs -ls -l /` and see what comes back.  Usually a permissions error comes back explicitly, but lets have a gander at what the root path looks like.  I wonder if the file system was never formatted.

Comment: This might be better at serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to setup a user directory is to login to Hue as an admin and create a user account. This will create a directory in HDFS located at /user/yourusername with the correct permissions to work in.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved. I created the folders in terminal.

6b.  hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser

7. Put this file to HDFS:
   hadoop fs -put file1.txt /user/hduser/file1.txt
   hadoop fs -put file.txt file.txt

Answer (score 0):

You should create /user folder at first.

> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user

Comment: The `-p` flag means that you don't have to create the parent directory first.